# wordpress multisite permalink structure: mostly subdomains but not all

Tags: multisite, permalinks, url-rewriting

I've got a Wordpress multi-site install with three (related) sites, and it works great. Previously, each site had its own totally unique domain name which I was managing with the [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) plugin. So, something like:

```
site.com
anothersite.org
random.net
```

Now, I need to have all three sites running on the same domain, however, I have a strange permalink structure that needs to be implemented. Namely, two of the sites will be on the *same* subdomain (using a language code in the path to distinguish them), while the third will be on its own subdomain:

```
ca.site.com/en/    (previously site.com)
ca.site.com/fr/    (previously anothersite.org)
us.site.com/en/    (previously random.net)
```

I have access to the httpd.conf file, and have been trying to setup up RewriteRules... but I can't get it working, and I'm not especially sure if this is even the correct direction. If someone could just point me in the right direction that would be amazing, thanks

Comment: As far as I know subdomains and sub-directories are mutually exclusive settings.